# Azure Functions Trigger Timer Trigger locally

Tags: azure-functions

I have a `timerTrigger` that I want to locally debug on VS Code, so I do the `func host start --debug vscode` on the root where `host.json` is:

```
PS C:\Users\user\code\azure\functions> func host start --debug vscode

                  %%%%%%
                 %%%%%%
            @   %%%%%%    @
          @@   %%%%%%      @@
       @@@    %%%%%%%%%%%    @@@
     @@      %%%%%%%%%%        @@
       @@         %%%%       @@
         @@      %%%       @@
           @@    %%      @@
                %%
                %

[11/28/2017 10:21:30 PM] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Users\user\code\azure\functions\host.json'
[11/28/2017 10:21:30 PM] Host configuration file read:
[11/28/2017 10:21:30 PM] {}
info: Worker.Node.1b2b2430-8e1c-4d66-a3e9-bb1672be5ac2[0]
      Start Process: node  --inspect=5858 "C:\Users\user\.azurefunctions\bin\workers\node\dist\src\nodejsWorker.js" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 59865 --workerId 1b2b2430-8e1c-4d66-a3e9-bb1672be5ac2 --requestId f52eeb9b-d46b-4791-8504-3f94f380c1e2
[11/28/2017 10:21:31 PM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[11/28/2017 10:21:31 PM] Starting Host (HostId=swlaptop2062-377256582, Version=2.0.11370.0, ProcessId=16752, Debug=True, ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=0, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[11/28/2017 10:21:31 PM] Found the following functions:
[11/28/2017 10:21:31 PM] Host.Functions.TriggerHR
[11/28/2017 10:21:31 PM]
info: Worker.Node.1b2b2430-8e1c-4d66-a3e9-bb1672be5ac2[0]
      Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5858/77692ee0-e279-4463-9974-f8412f5dd3fd
info: Worker.Node.1b2b2430-8e1c-4d66-a3e9-bb1672be5ac2[0]
      For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Listening on http://localhost:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...
launch.json for VSCode configured.
info: Worker.Node.1b2b2430-8e1c-4d66-a3e9-bb1672be5ac2[0]
      Worker 1b2b2430-8e1c-4d66-a3e9-bb1672be5ac2 connecting on 127.0.0.1:59865
[11/28/2017 10:21:32 PM] Job host started
[11/28/2017 10:21:32 PM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000EF9214DA'.
```

Then I do `func run TriggerHR`. I get:

```
Error: unknown argument run
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.0.1-beta.21)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.11370.0
Usage: func [context] [context] <action> [-/--options]
```

Here is the `function.json` on `TriggerHR`:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */30 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am on v2 runtime. I even try `http://localhost:7071/api/myTimer` and I get `localhost cannot be found` even though `http://localhost:7071` gives me that smiley face window that my app is running.

Here is how it's laid out:

```
- TriggerHR (Timer function)
--index.js
--function.json
|
|
- host.json
- local.settings.json
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. Make sure you're using the right version of the core tools based on what version of functions you're trying to use. Basically this line `Function Runtime Version: 2.0.11370.0` tells you that you're currently running the core tools that target functions v2.
2. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#run-functions-locally) for documentation on developing locally.
3. The core tools for functions v2 do not support the `func run` command. If you want to test your timer function without waiting for it to run on its schedule, you can use the admin API to invoke it. Try sending a POST request to `http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/TriggerHR`. See the `Non-HTTP triggered functions` section in the above doc for more info.
4. Not sure if you're already trying this, but there is now an extension for VS code designed to make working with azure functions really easy, including debugging. See [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions).

Comment: 1. yes, I am using the `@core` version. 2. Yes, I read that. 3. I am using POSTMAN to send a `POST` request to `http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/myTimer` and `http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/TriggerHR` with no luck. 4. Yes, I have installedd that.

Comment: what does "no luck" mean? What's the HTTP response code?

Comment: Doing `curl --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/TriggerHR` returns nothing. Do you execute it using the `name` property from `function.json`? For POSTMAN, I get a 400 Bad Request

Comment: I get 404 not found actually.

Comment: To anyone looking at this now, I had the same problem as @nn2 - including an empty json body fixed it (i.e {} )

Comment: Same issue, the post to admin/function does not work. I get 400 error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55063821/debug-azure-functions-locally/55067597

Comment: same here, get 400 when using curl: `curl --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"input":"example"}' http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/MainTriggerEntry`. It works via Postman for some reason though...

Comment: As Esben suggested, using an epty {} with no quotes helps when using curl: curl --`request POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data {} http://localhost:7071/admin/functions/MainTriggerEntry`. See how we don't wrap `{}` in double quotes

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
[FunctionName("YourFunctionName")]
    public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 30 17 * * *"
        #if DEBUG
        ,RunOnStartup = true
        #endif
        )] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
    {
       //your code
    }
```